# UITabbarController in Xcode 8 shows a blue rectangle inside a storyboard view

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

How can I fix this ? I can't see anything at all.

[image]

Comment: uncheck Editor -> Canvas -> Show Bounds Rectangles

Comment: @OMGHaveFun, didn't work :(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### **Edit:**

This bug will be fixed in the next release of Xcode 8.2, make sure to update. [Xcode 8.2 Release Notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.2_beta/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_8.2_beta.pdf)

---

Ok, so I found out how to remove the blue rectangle.

If I add an image to the button of the tab bar the rectangle will disappear.

[image]

---

### **And The end result:**

[image]

Comment: I have XCode 8.2.1 and this bug wasn't fixed, but adding an image did fix it.

Comment: For me it was the opposite, if I have a picture the blue box appears, if I put a text it disappears. In 8.2.1 put the button tint as clear color also resolved for me.

Answer (score 0):

just set images to each tab bar in every view controller. and this bug will go automatically. in  my case this was the solution.