# Solid blue rectangle on XCode Tab Bar View Controllers that won't go away?

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently looked at my app's `main.storyboard` and realized that there is a big, blue, rectangular box covering half of some of my viewcontrollers (image is pasted here). Only the `UIViewControllers` connected to the `UITabBarController` are affected. I did not even realize that this had happened, despite having moved to xCode7 a while ago. It is a bit annoying since dropping any UI element into the view controller causes that element to 'go behind' this blue region and so I can't see them. It is not that the default color is set to blue or anything; it is not a clickable object to even set display parameters to. Anybody have any ideas how to fix this... or even what it is?

Edit: This is not a problem singular to this particular XCode project. Any new project I create and insert a `TabBarViewController` has this issue.  
Edit 2: Problem disappeared then came back. Posted the problem (which persists on for even a brand new xcode project with tab bar view controller). It is at https://github.com/AlekPiasecki/XcodeProblems 
Edit 3: To anybody that has the same issue: This is almost certainly due to hardware. I have the latest version of XCode (the XCode 8 beta) and OS Sierra installed on my computer. The github post continues to have the same issue for me, but it appears fine on computers which do not have these betas installed. As far as fixing the problem now that I am stuck with these Xcode and OS versions... I still have no idea.

[image]

Comment: Is your UIViewController connected to a UITabBarController? Please update your question with a picture of the entire storyboard.

Comment: @kabiroberai yes it is connected to the `UITabBarController`. There are three instances of this occurring in the story board and all three are all connected to it.

Comment: @AlekPiasecki and do all of your `UIViewController`s have tab bar icons?

Comment: @kabiroberai and yes they do have tab bar icons

Comment: @AlekPiasecki huh. I had a similar problem, but I solved it by adding tab bar icons to all of my view controllers. The solution to your issue may be similar though.

Comment: @kabiroberai you added tab bar icons to ALL of your viewcontrollers? The app I am making is rather large and there is a large amount of viewcontrollers. Would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: @AlekPiasecki No, I only added them to the root view controllers of the `UITabBarController`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125558/discussion-between-kabiroberai-and-alek-piasecki).

Comment: Do you know Xcode's Document Outline? If not, you may show it with menu "Editor" -> "Show Document Outline". Sometimes I am not able to click on things in the storyboard. In those cases it helps to find them in the document outline. Click on a parent view in the scene, this view is then also selected in the document outline so you more easily see where you are.

Comment: @RainerSchwarze yes I know the Document Outline. It is not an item/UI element that shows up on that either

Comment: "Any new project I create and insert a TabBarViewController has this issue." Please create one, then, and post it on github or similar so I can download it and see for myself. Blip me when you've done that. Thanks!

Comment: @matt I just made a new XCode project to upload it to github and it suddenly didn't have the problem... Though I am, currently, using a different wifi (and therefore IP) than I did when I first encountered the problem. Not sure why this is. Will check later tonight at the original IP and update you

Comment: @matt the problem was randomly fixed

Comment: I've voted to close as being unreproducible, but please don't take it personally. If even you can't reproduce it, it really is unreproducible! I don't doubt that you saw what you saw, but who knows what was going on...

Comment: @matt I am working on the app with a colleague and the problem persists on his computer for some reason. Not sure why this is since the file is shared on box and the problem does not occur on my computer

Comment: It sounds like something is wrong with his computer. Could even be a hardware issue. It doesn't sound like an Xcode problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125748/discussion-between-alek-piasecki-and-matt).

Comment: @matt did you see that I put the link to the github upload?

Comment: Hi @AlekPiasecki! Yes, did you see that I downloaded it and saw no problem? I replied over in the discussion you set up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITabbarController in Xcode 8 shows a blue rectangle inside a storyboard view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540095/uitabbarcontroller-in-xcode-8-shows-a-blue-rectangle-inside-a-storyboard-view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an image to the `TabBarViewController` fixes this issue. The blue box goes into whatever size the image is, so making the image really small (like, say, a pixel) shrinks the blue box so that is invisible (essentially). This works in practice as a solution, but don't know how to truly permanently get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks @Alek Piasecki, at least now i can keep working on my projekt.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Xcode error that will be fixed in 8.2 release.
This is the Apple official note about this problem.

Look in the link for Interface Builder > Resolved Issues > UITabBarController
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html